# can't get perl multi-line substitution right

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I am having trouble understanding how multiline matching works in perl
I have a file where I want to remove any appearance of:

```
@keyword{
```

or

```
@keyword
{
```

in both case, @ is the first character of the line.

I can do it with two separate instructions (with 'perl -p0777'):

```
s/\n\@keyword\{//
s/\n\@keyword\n\{//
```

but I thought the following would work too

```
s/\n\@keyword\n?\{//
```

and it does not. It does not catch the second case and I cannot understand why ???

any explanation ?

Comment: Contrary to your claims, `s/\n\@keyword\n?\{//` works if `s/\n\@keyword\n\{//` works.

Comment: When there are multiple occurrences of any of the 2 patterns, and perl is given the -0777 arguments it only works for the first instance of each pattern. The reason is obvious (once one understands the problem) and I gave it in my "answer". But no, it does not work without the 'g' at the end of the perl instruction.

Comment: When there are multiple occurrences of any of the 2 pattern, both versions only do the first, so my comment stands.

Answer (score -1):

Ahhhhh !
just got it.
Because of perl -p0777, the whole file is only one line,
expressions are matched once on the entire file, so each statement matched exactly one pattern.
The solution was to put 'g' at the end:

```
s/\n\@keyword\n?\{//g
```

But now another one.

I first started without the -0777 option
and I thought that

```
s/^\@keyword\n?\{//m
```

would work.
But again it did not catch the second case (pattern on two lines).
Can you explain why ?

Comment: SO is not a forum. In the future, if you have a new question, asked it as a question. /// `m` only affects what `^` and `$` match. It can't possibly cause the pattern `^\@keyword\n?\{` to match the string `@keyword␊`.

Comment: I don't quite understand this comment. I had a genuine question (as witnessed by the question marks at the end of the 1st message). It happened that right after asking the question, and still trying to solve the problem (I spent a full morning on it), I found the answer. But even then, this solution is not satisfactory because -0777 prevents me from doing any line based transformations (I have other transformations to apply). So I would like to know how I could do it. And, again, I asked a genuine question as why my tentative solution did not work.

Comment: As for `///m`, I understood that putting `\n` in a regexp changes how `^` and `$` are interpreted and that `///m` brings back the usual behavior. May be I am wrong? The question remains how I could do the transformations I need without invoking `perl -0777` ... ?

Comment: Re "*The question remains how I could do the transformations I need without invoking perl -0777 ... ?*" This is the first time you've asked this question, and it can't be answered in a comment. If you want to ask a new question, post a Question.